# N-Body Simulation - How to choose the softening factor?

Tags: opengl, cuda, physics, simulation

I am in the process of writing a simplified version of All Pairs N-Body simulation. I am using CUDA/OpenGL to implement the algorithm and visualize the simulation. I am assuming that all bodies are spheres of uniform radius such that the mass of each sphere is the only difference(Assume that all spheres have radius == 1). Now, I would like to know how to choose the softening factor in the equation of Acceleration?
[image: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/elementLinks/680equ02.jpg]

What I am thinking of is that `epsilon == 2` is a good choice because it is the moment when two spheres collide in my case. Is that a reasonable choice? Is there a simple explanation of how to choose the softening factor?

I have looked at Chapter 31 of GPU Gems 3 but it doesn't say what the chosen value is and how you would choose a suitable value. I have looked at some research papers but I am unable to penetrate those academic papers on my own.

Comment: Might this not be a better fit for the Physics SE?

Comment: An even better fit for the [scientific computation SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 2 meters? Angstroms? AU?

Comment: @Bart I can't say for sure if the folk there would be interested in such a question mainly because the softening factor is related to limited precision I have on the numerical type(in my case double or float). Do you suggest that this is more suitable over there?

Comment: @AraK Well, it's more of a "this does not seem to be a programming issue"-suggestion. So I was wondering if another SE might be more helpful to you, although I'm not sure about them. If you get good answers here, great.

Comment: I've deleted my answer in light of the excellent linked paper. For reference though: `epsilon==2` is an invalid choice because 2 is a dimensionless quantity and that expression should be in terms of length. One must first convert the equations to dimensionless form before one can give a dimensionless choice for `epsilon`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization

Comment: Agree this should be posted on physics or computational science SE, not SO.

Answer (score 4):

The right softening length for a problem depends upon lots of things -- timestep, configuration, scale of the problems of interest, choice of integrator, etc.  Generally speaking, if you want to suppress two-body relaxation you want some function of the Hill radius [as opposed to the physical radius, as it looks like you want to suppress the effects of close encounters, not mock up a collision.]

See [Walter Dehnen's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0011568v1.pdf) on the subject of choosing an optimal softening (although I'm dating myself a little by citing that; probably there are more up-to-date references).